# Applicationclass error when opening excel workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to open an excel workbook from a simple vb application.
Each time I press the button to open excel, I get the following error:

"Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass'   "

I have selected the Microsoft.interop.office.excel reference

I have also tried to just use .application instead of .applicationclass but that didn't make a difference either.

I searched previous asked questions about this, but those solutions didn't to anything for me.

See below for my code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim oExcel As excel.ApplicationClass
    Dim oBook As excel.WorkbookClass
    Dim oBooks As excel.Workbooks

    'Start Excel and open the workbook.'
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.Visible = True
    oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks
    oBook = oBooks.Open("c:\book1.xls")


    End sub
```

Any suggestions for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What references do you have set? I'd ordinarily expect to see a new Excel instance created with Excel.Application rather than ApplicationClass.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8184013/4243498) which looks similar.

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler 
This is the reference i have set: Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: @ChipsLetten
That solution didn't do the trick...

Comment: Did you get this figured out yet? I'm wondering if your alias name in the imports statement is screwing things up, since "Excel" is already declared within that namespace.  Maybe try `Imports MyExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.  Did you also add a *reference* to this library in the project?